# javascript: setting a variable to a ctx function such as moveTo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, variables, html5-canvas

If I execute `ctx.moveTo` directly, it works just fine. But if I set a variable to `ctx.moveTo` (`var f=ctx.moveTo;`) then `f===ctx.moveTo` is `true` but `f(0,0)` fails with an error while `ctx.moveTo(0,0)` works fine. Why? I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of javascript--what am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the association with the `ctx` object. When you call the function via the copy of the reference, you lose `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the context (`this` in this case) to the call. For that you can use `bind()`.

Calls like `moveTo()` need to access `this` internally and expect it to be the context. But `f()` is by default only associated with itself and doesn't have access to the context via `this` internally. Binding it to context will allow the internal calls to access `this` as with the original context.

```
var f = ctx.moveTo.bind(ctx);
f(x, y);
```

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var f = ctx.fillRect.bind(ctx); // fillRect instead of moveTo for demo

f(10, 10, 100, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```